# Time taken by an alternating quantity to reach a particular value for the second time within one cycle

Tags: signal

How do we find the time taken by the current i=20sin(314t) to reach a particular value( not 0 or the peak value) for the second time within one cycle

Comment: This question is not specific enough. What kind of quantity? In what way is it alternating? What's a cycle in this situation?

Comment: It's actually a text book question .. And the signal is a sine wave..whose eqn is i=20sin(314wt)

Comment: You need to think about this for a little bit more. On a sine wave, the value will repeat at some point in the future. Define that equation as i=20sin(314w(t + X)). Where X is the unknown future time. The values are the same and you can set the equations equal. 20sin(314wt) = 20sin(314w(t+X)). Does that help?

Comment: To calculate the time you need to know the frequency,f, (wt = 2*pi*f*t) in your equation there are two unknowns

Comment: Wouldn't the above solution of X be 0??

Comment: Im sorry there is no w( omega) in the equation

Comment: X=0 does not help you at all. That is your starting point...

Comment: so the equation is actually 20sin(314t)

Comment: choose a value for i and solve the equation for t - your scientific calculator should have an inverse sin function. Set to radian measurement.

Comment: Do you want to solve this mathematically as an exercise, implement it in a mostly analog circuit, or would you like to put it through the ADC of a cheap processor and find it algorithmically?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, not electronic design.

Comment: I would like to solve it mathematically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a run through in [wxMaxima](http://andrejv.github.io/wxmaxima/) (an excellent free computer algebra system) of a solution for this problem. I picked the second occurrence of I = 10 (Ix below) Ipeak is the peak of the waveform, 20 in this case:

[image: Maxima workbook]

Answer (score 0):

What shape is the signal was my first thought believing you may want some technical or mathematical answer. So now I'm assuming you want to know how would a circuit find the 2nd point within one cycle of an arbitrary waveform.

I am also assuming that the time taken to reach that 2nd point is based on the first point being taken as the datum, t = 0.

The simple answer is use a comparator circuit and a microprocessor that is counting high speed clocks. The first time the point is passed causes the comparator to change state from 1 to 0 OR from 0 to 1. This event can trigger your microprocessor to start counting. The second event will cause the comparator to reverse the zero and one event and this is used to stop the timer.

And now you have a count in your microprocessor that represents the time difference between E1 and E2.

One thing remains to be added. The point in the cycle you were looking for has to be fed into the comparator as an analogue reference point. This can be done from the micro using a DAC. How you inform the micro what value you are looking for is trivial.

Also, of some interest (maybe) is that if the waveform was a single event, it may not have a "2nd point".

**Tricky parts**: No it's never as easy as it sounds. Since writing the original answer the OP has furnished the question with the frequency and shape; 50Hz and sinusiodal. Does this make it easier? A bit becuase it is fairly low frequency. The main problems remaining are the comparator and the point it switches - if the circuit doesn't include hysterisis then the points will be as exact as the comparator input offset voltage error allows BUT noise can cause "early" or late triggers on E2 and E1 independantly.

With hysterisis (noise avoidance method) the timing will be out by a factor based on the amount of hysterisis. It's a compromise; and the likely solution (because it is a sinewave) is a good filter to remove noise with a tiny bit of hysterisis.

Comparator response times should be OK but use a fast device - it's easy to lose a few hunderd usecs on a rise time that's a bit sloppy.

Comment: I don't think that's all that complicated because it was a problem without any solution in my "basics to electrical engineering" book in the chapter "alternating quantities". The question is how to find the time taken by the alternating current to reach a particular value other than 0 or its peak value for the second time within one cycle

Comment: @DannyPaul  In theory, theory matches practice.  In practice, not so much.  Just because it was in a basic EE book does not mean it is easy.

Comment: @DavidKessner too true so I've amended answer to point to potential problems.